# EntityFrameworkを使用した場合のSQL Serverのインデックスの有効性について教えてください。

Tags: c#, database, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-azure

EntityFramework6、ASP.NET(MVC)プロジェクト(C#)で初めて開発しています。
DBはAzure SQLデータベースです。
IDが主キーで、name,ageなどのカラムがあるmemberというテーブルが検索に時間がかかるので、ageに非クラスタ化インデックスを作成しました。
その状態で以下の実行プランを見るとnameのデータを取得するためキー参照となります。

```
select id, name, age from member where age >= 25
```

それを回避するには、(age, name)で複合インデックスやIncludeオプションで作成すると良いようです。

そこで沸いた疑問なのですが、EntityFrameworkの場合、以下のようにして取得します。
SELECT句を指定していないのでカラムすべてを取得していると思うのですが、インデックスは効かないということになるのでしょうか？

```
using (var db = new SampleContext())
{
    var query = db.member.Where(m => m.age >= 25);

    foreach (var member in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id={0},name={1},age={2}", member.id, member.name, member.age);
    }
}
```

EntityFrameworkを使う場合はインデックスは無意味になってしまうのか？ということと、その場合処理時間の短縮はどうしたらよいのかお聞きしたいです。
初心者なので色々おかしいかもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

---

（追記）
以下のコードでSQLを取得してみました。

```
using (var db = new SampleContext())
{
    db.Database.Log = sql => { Console.WriteLine(sql); };

    var query1= db.member.Where(e => e.age == 25);

    var query2 = db.member.Where(e => e.age == 25).Select(e => new { e.id, e.name, e.age } );
}

// query1
//SELECT 
//    [Extent1].[id] AS [id],
//    [Extent1].[name] AS [name],
//    [Extent1].[mail_address] AS [mail_address],
//    [Extent1].[type] AS [type],
//    [Extent1].[age] AS [age]
//    FROM [dbo].[member] AS [Extent1]
//    WHERE [Extent1].[age] = @p__linq__0
//
// query2
//SELECT 
//    1 AS [C1]
//    [Extent1].[id] AS [id]
//    [Extent1].[name] AS [name]
//    [Extent1].[age] AS [age]
//    FROM [dbo].[member] AS [Extent1]
//    WHERE [Extent1].[age] = @p__linq__0
```

このSQLで実行プランを見たところ、主キー(id)しかインデックスがない状態ではどちらもClustered Index Scan 100%でした。
以下のようにIncludeオプションでインデックスを作成した状態では、query1はIndex Seek50%、キー参照50%で、query2はIndex Seek100%でした。
`CREATE INDEX IX_member ON member (age) INCLUDE(name)`

100回ぐらい処理時間を計測したところ、平均して30ミリ秒程度ですがquery2の方が遅かったです。
既存プログラムでは、query1の使い方がほとんどなので、そうなるとインデックスはあんまり効果ないということになるのでしょうか？

Includeオプションで他のカラムをすべて指定しておくという使い方はアリなのでしょうか？

こちらの利用も初めてですみません。引き続きよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問内容と実験が一致していないように思います。EF6でインデックスが有効かどうかを知りたいのならばEF6での実行と生SQLでの実行を比較するべきでは？

Comment: 生SQLというのは、このプログラム上でADO.NETなどを使ってということですか？
** Entity FrameworkがどのようなSQL文を生成したのか  **
を取得して、それをSSMSで実行プランを取得することが
** DBエンジンがSQL文をどのように解釈したのか  **
になると思ったのですが。

Comment: 実行プランを確認してインデックスを使用したプランになっているのならばインデックスを使用するはずです。もし本当にその通りになっているか確認したいのならば生SQLと比較したりといって実験をしてよいと思います。ただ、追記での実験はEF6は無関係に二つのSQLを比較しているように思えます。純粋に二つのSQLの速度差に関しての疑問ならば別質問を立てるべきで、そうするとEFには全く興味がないけどRDBMSには興味がある人がたどり着きやすくなります。（回答者も同じ疑問に行き着いた人も）

Comment: EF6無関係なのでしょうか。。。SQLServerを知りたいのかもしれないのですが。OracleだとSelect句にインデックス指定されていない列があったとしてもインデックス効きますよね。でもSQLServerだとそうではない。その場合、EFを使ってプログラムを書く場合はquery2の書き方をするべきなのか、全カラムIncludeオプションで作っとけばいいよ、なのかがわからないのです。

Comment: すみません、DBは私はあまり詳しくはないです。インデックス指定せずにインデックス効くってどうやってるんだろう。

Comment: 少なくともインデックスを贅沢にするのには構築速度や容量のデメリットがあり、下手すると読み取りすらもDBを混乱させることがあるはずです、私の知識では。

Answer (score 3):

Entity Frameworkは魔法でもなんでもなく、指示に従ってSQL文を生成したうえで、生成したSQL文をDBエンジンに実行させます。生成したSQL文は[データベース操作のログ記録と受信](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)で確認することができます。

DBエンジン側は受け取ったSQL文を解析し、インデックスが使えるかを判断します。

ですので、

- Entity FrameworkがどのようなSQL文を生成したのか
- DBエンジンがSQL文をどのように解釈したのか

の2段階に分けて判断してください。

---

> 100回ぐらい処理時間を計測したところ、平均して30ミリ秒程度ですがquery2の方が遅かったです。
> 既存プログラムでは、query1の使い方がほとんどなので、そうなるとインデックスはあんまり効果ないということになるのでしょうか？

相対値として30ms程度とのことですが、絶対値はいかがでしょうか？ もともと短時間で済む処理であれば、インデックスの効果が薄くなってしまうのかもしれません。また、このクエリはプログラム全体の処理の中で有意のあるウェイトを占める処理なのでしょうか？ [80:20の法則](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%B3%95%E5%89%87)という言葉もあるように、十分に高速な部分をさらに高速化しても全体としては得るものがありません。

Comment: 単純な検索なのですがしょっちゅう呼び出されます。この処理に限らず、EFとSQLServerの仕様というか、使い方的には、「query1のような書きかた(ほとんどのカラムを取得したい場合)は、インデックスが効かない」実験を通して理解しました。また、その場合に回避する手段としてIncludeオプションで他のカラムをすべて指定しておくという使い方が妥当なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

一般論としては、select * from table where index_column = x でもインデックスは使われます。
但し、参照するテーブルの件数が少ない場合、オプティマイザが全件取得の方が効率が良いと判断する可能性もあります。この場合は、インデックスは使われません。

おそらくamamさんは、インデックスが利用されることと、インデックスの参照だけでクエリの実行が完了することを混同されているのではないかと思います。

includeオプションで全てのカラムを指定するというのは、本来テーブルとして利用すべきものを全てIndexの領域にも保存するということですので、異常な使い方です（もしかしたらその方が良い場面もあるかもしれませんが）。